# Is there a way to push pages into the navigation stack from top or bottom in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, maui, .net-maui.shell

I wish to customize the default direction(sideways) that is used for navigating between the pages and instead use top or bottom directions for page navigations in .NET MAUI, is it possible?

I have not found any articles which support that this can be done.

Comment: Hi, please explain more and better what you're trying to archive.

Comment: If you mean page transition like [this in Xamarin](https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/xamarin-forms-page-transitions), check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74973199/net-maui-navigation-animation) and follow [this spec](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6).

Comment: If you are trying to change the "swipe" direction, that might be problematic. Mobile platforms don't usually swipe up/down to change pages, because up/down is used to scroll content that is taller than the device screen. Are you designing your pages so that they always exactly fill the screen, regardless of device size?

Comment: If you want to navigate between the pages by the swip left and right, you can use the SwipeGestureRecognizer for the layout in the contentpage.